# Java updating mysql row if id already exists

Tags: java, mysql

I have a simple form with 5 fields. (txtID, txtFirstName, txtLastName, txtCheque, txtSavings). All I want to do is inserting these fields into my database table "accounts". Before that step I want to check if the ID from my txtID field already exists in my database. If yes then I want to update the database row with the content from the fields. And if not I want to create a new row with the content. So far the check if the ID exists in my DB works but if click on my btn I get the following error message: I dont relly know what I'm doing wrong.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
>   server version for the right syntax to use near '(LastName,
>   FirstName,Cheque,Savings) VALUES('Tester','Markus','450.00','50.00" at
>   line 1

```
private void btnUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try{
            String id = txtID.getText();
            String checkid ="SELECT * FROM accounts where ID=?";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(checkid);
            pst.setString(1, id);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            boolean recordAdded = false;
            while(!rs.next()){            
                 recordAdded = true;
            }
            if(recordAdded){
              // the statement for inserting goes here.
            }else{
                String sql ="UPDATE accounts SET " + "(LastName,FirstName,Cheque,Savings) VALUES" + "(?,?,?,?)";
                pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1,txtLastName.getText());
                pst.setString(2,txtFirstName.getText());                
                pst.setString(3,txtCheque.getText());
                pst.setString(4,txtSavings.getText());
                pst.executeUpdate();
                getAllAccounts();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Customer Updated");
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        finally {
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
                getAllAccounts();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: your update syntax is incorrect, check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html. also you are updating whole table, not the record with id = `id`. try `String sql ="UPDATE accounts SET LastName = ?, FirstName = ?, Cheque = ?, Savings = ? where id = ?";`

Comment: Thanks @guleryuz ! It works now. Its still weired as I used the above code in a different project and it works ... Thanks anyway for your fast response :)

Comment: OK this is getting strange :( If I have no ID in my txtID field and I hit the button the JFrame freezes. Even if don't have any code inserted yet into the if(recordAdded). If I add a number to my txtID field the check works perfect and updates the database entry. Is there generally a issue with this code?

Comment: yes :).  if there is no record with id = `id` then `!rs.next()` will be `true` and `while` loops forever. this makes your application freeze.

Comment: Yeah you're right :) I changed it to an if :) Thanks again @guleryuz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you let me to make some changes in your code?

```
private void btnUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    try {

        String sql = "UPDATE accounts SET LastName = ?, FirstName = ?, Cheque = ?, Savings = ? where id = ?";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,txtLastName.getText());
        pst.setString(2,txtFirstName.getText());                
        pst.setString(3,txtCheque.getText());
        pst.setString(4,txtSavings.getText());
        pst.setString(5,txtID.getText());
        int updatedRowCount = pst.executeUpdate();
        // no record with id = txtID
        if(updatedRowCount == 0) {

            pst.close();                

            sql = "insert into accounts (ID,LastName,FirstName,Cheque,Savings) values (?,?,?,?,?,?) ";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1,txtID.getText());
            pst.setString(2,txtLastName.getText());
            pst.setString(3,txtFirstName.getText());
            pst.setString(4,txtCheque.getText());
            pst.setString(5,txtSavings.getText());
            pst.executeUpdate();

        }

        getAllAccounts();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, updatedRowCount > 0 ? "Customer Updated" : "Customer Inserted");

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        getAllAccounts();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    finally {
        try{
            pst.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```